# Using form method in a template Wordpress page

Tags: forms

I have created a template page that build a calendar using that script:

https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-web-calendar-in-php
It works fine when i change month but i got a 404 error when changing year.

I assume there is a relation with the GET method and htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) but i don't know more...

Could please someone help me  ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you provide your own code to see where the problem is ?

Comment: i have just resolve the problem replacing all occurrence of 'year' par 'mastering'. It seems year is reserved by PHP

Answer (score 0):

i have just resolve the problem replacing all occurrence of 'year' par 'mastering'. It seems year is reserved by PHP